# Hyperleger Indy - TheOrgBook Module Build Failure due to Node and NPM Issue

Tags: node.js, angular, hyperledger, blockchain, hyperledger-indy

I have deployed VON Network and Permitify Modules of Hyperledger Indy SSI VC Demo in MacOS successfully. I am facing issues in TheOrgBook setup. However TheOrgBook Demo is failing even after trying the hot fix suggested in the GitHub [Issue #26](https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain-Identity/indy-ssivc-tutorial/issues/26).

```
ERROR in ./src/main.ts
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve './$$_gendir/app/app.module.ngfactory' in '/opt/app-root/src/src'
ERROR in Error: Error encountered resolving symbol values statically. Could not resolve localize-router relative to /opt/app-root/src/src/app/app.module.ts., resolving symbol AppModule in /opt/app-root/src/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in /opt/app-root/src/src/app/app.module.ts, resolving symbol AppModule in /opt/app-root/src/src/app/app.module.ts

    npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE

    npm ERR! Failed at the tob-web@0.0.1 postinstall script 'ng build --prod --base-href ${NG_BASE_HREF:-/} ${NG_BUILD_FLAGS:-} && cp dist/themes/_active/index.html dist/index.html'.
    npm ERR! Make sure you have the latest version of node.js and npm installed.
    npm ERR! If you do, this is most likely a problem with the tob-web package,
    npm ERR! not with npm itself.

    npm ERR! You can get information on how to open an issue for this project with:
    npm ERR!     npm bugs tob-web
    npm ERR! Or if that isn't available, you can get their info via:
    npm ERR!     npm owner ls tob-web
    npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.

    npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
    npm ERR!     /opt/app-root/src/npm-debug.log
    Build failed
```

Answer (score 0):

Wrong example, try this one [link](https://github.com/hyperledger/education/blob/master/LFS171x/indy-material/nodejs/README.md)